# How to assign user to group in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, node.js

I have two tables in MySQL database one is named 'users' the other is 'groups'.

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `full_name` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `position` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `company` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `email` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)

CREATE TABLE `groups` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `group_name` varchar(30) NOT NULL
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

How do I assign a user to a group? I was thinking of joining the tables together but I don't know how to start? I am open to try this another way if joining tables is complex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create a bridge table like below and insert `users.id` and `groups.id` in to that table.

```
Users_group (userid,groupid)
```

If one user can belong to multiple groups, you can make `userid` and `groupid` as composite primary key

Assuming you are trying to insert the `users` and `group` combinations.

Comment: Can I try something like INSERT INTO ? I can add another column inside my groups table and then add the userid to that table once I have retrieved it.

Comment: you can do that, but its not a good way of designing. Say for example in the future, a report needs to show the groups (only) info, you will end up querying the entire `Users_group` table, which is not an optimal way and also data will be redundant. Like, if you want to update a `group_name` in future, you must update in multiple rows. Yes you can use `INSERT INTO`.

Comment: I think the bridge table is the way to go since I want a cleaner design. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @JohnnyEnglish please give GGadde credit by giving him the solution.